# Expand macro inside lstlisting and apply syntax highlighting

Tags: macros, listings, expansion, highlighting

I'm wondering if there's a way to expand a macro inside a `lstlisting` environment which automatically applies syntax highlighting to the expanded text.

For example, the listing in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    keywords={function},
    escapeinside={|}{|}
}
\def\fbar{function bar ();}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[]
function foo ();
|\fbar|
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

should produce this output:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There is now!** <sub><sup><sub>I also hate listings now :)</sub></sup></sub>

Well, sort of. Read on and you'll see.

First, the `escapechar=<char>` option is, for our disappointment, just a shorthand of `escapeinside=<char><char>`. Not terribly useful, if you ask me. The docs and the sources don't point to anything other than that.

I implemented a `cschar=<char>` option which will use the `<char>` as a escape character (in TeX's, not `listings`' meaning). I recycled some code from `listings`' `escapeinside` and made it start a `\lst@scan@csname` thing. This scanner grabs as much characters between `a-z` and `A-Z` (no `\m@cr@s` allowed) as possible and builds a control sequence out of them, or it grabs one non-letter characters and build a control character. The built control sequence/character is then expanded (once) and retokenized using `expl3`'s `\tl_rescan:nn` (I didn't have the patience to copy its definition) and reinserted in the token stream for `listings` to do its thing. If the expanded control sequence happens to have another control sequence inside, it is later expanded as well, working recursively.

Beware that this is an *emulation* of how TeX builds a control sequence, so it has some <s>bugs</s> features that aren't worth a check. For instance, `\fbar hello` will print `function bar(); hello`, with a space between, while TeX would expand to `function bar();hello`. This makes it impossible for you to get, for instance `function bar();hello` because `\fbarhello` would be interpreted as one (undefined) control sequence. You'd need to define a control sequence `\def\hello{hello}` and use `\fbar\hello`.

Here's the code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{expl3}

\makeatletter
\gdef\lst@CSEscape#1{%
    \lst@CArgX #1\relax\lst@CDefX
        {}%
        {\lst@ifdropinput\else
         \lst@TrackNewLines\lst@OutputLostSpace \lst@XPrintToken
         \lst@InterruptModes
         \lst@EnterMode{\lst@TeXmode}{\lst@modetrue}%
         \let\do\@makeother\dospecials
         \let\lst@grabbed@csname\@empty
         \expandafter\lst@scan@csname%
         \fi}%
        {}}
\lst@Key{cschar}{}
    {\ifx\@empty#1\@empty
       \let\lst@CSChar\relax
     \else
       \def\lst@CSChar{\lst@CSEscape{#1}}%
     \fi}
\let\lst@explicit@space=\ %
\lst@AddToHook{SelectCharTable}{\lst@CSChar}
\def\lst@afterfi#1#2\fi{\fi#1}
\def\lst@scan@csname#1{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \lst@afterfi{\lst@dispatch@csname{#1}}%
  \else
    \lst@afterfi{%
      \uppercase{\def\lst@tmpa{#1}}%
      \expandafter\lst@scan@csname@\expandafter
        {\number\expandafter`\lst@tmpa}{#1}}%
  \fi}
\def\lst@scan@csname@#1#2{%
  \ifnum %      vv If you want to \maketatletter :)
    % \ifnum0#1>63 \expandafter0\else\expandafter1\fi
      \ifnum0#1>64 \expandafter0\else\expandafter1\fi
      \ifnum0#1<91 \expandafter0\else\expandafter1\fi
        =0
    \edef\lst@grabbed@csname{\lst@grabbed@csname\string#2}%
    \expandafter\lst@scan@csname
  \else
    \lst@afterfi{\lst@dispatch@csname{#2}}%
  \fi}
\def\lst@dispatch@csname#1{%
  \ifx\lst@grabbed@csname\@empty
    \if\detokenize{#1}\lst@char@space
      \lst@afterfi{\lst@afterfi{\lst@return@from@csname@{}{#1}}}%
    \else
      \lst@afterfi{\lst@afterfi{\lst@dispatch@csname@{\string#1}}}%
    \fi
  \else
    \lst@afterfi{\expandafter\lst@dispatch@csname@\expandafter{\lst@grabbed@csname}{#1}}%
  \fi}
\def\lst@dispatch@csname@#1{%
  \@ifundefined{#1}%
    {\PackageError{Listings}{! Undefined control sequence \@backslashchar#1}}%
    {\expandafter\lst@return@from@csname\csname#1\endcsname}}
\def\lst@return@from@csname#1{%
  \ifx#1\lst@explicit@space
    \lst@afterfi{\lst@return@from@csname@{}{}}%
  \else
    \lst@afterfi{\expandafter\lst@return@from@csname@\expandafter{#1}}%
  \fi}
\def\lst@return@from@csname@#1#2{%
  \lst@escapeend \lst@LeaveAllModes\lst@ReenterModes
  \lst@newlines\z@ \lst@whitespacefalse
  \lst@csescape@output{#1}{#2}}
\def\if@single@item#1{%
  \if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\@gobble#1}\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondofone
  \fi}
\def\lst@active@space{\lst@ProcessSpace}
\begingroup
\catcode`\|=0
\catcode`\[=1
\catcode`\]=2
\let\do\@makeother\dospecials
[|global|let|lst@char@space= ]
|endgroup
\def\lst@csescape@output#1#2{%
  \if@single@item{#2}%
    {%
      \ifnum
        \ifx\lst@active@space#2\expandafter1\else\expandafter0\fi
        \ifx\lst@char@space#2\expandafter1\else\expandafter0\fi
        >0
        \def\lst@aftertokens{\safescantokens{#1}\lst@ProcessSpace}%
      \else
        \def\lst@aftertokens{\safescantokens{#1#2}}%
      \fi
    }{%
      \def\lst@aftertokens{\safescantokens{#1#2}}%
    }%
  \lst@aftertokens
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \safescantokens #1 { \tl_rescan:nn {} {#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

```latex
\begin{document}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    keywords={function},
    cschar=\\,
}

\def\fbar{function bar ();}
\def\fuba{cat fuba ();}
\def\1{function first ();}

\begin{lstlisting}[]
function foo ();@12\ 3
\fbar\1{}@12\ 3
\fbar\fuba@12\ 3
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[]
function foo (); @12\ 3
\fbar{} @12\ 3
\fbar @12\ 3
\fbar\ @12\ 3
\end{lstlisting}

\lstset{cschar=|}

\begin{lstlisting}[]
function foo ();@12\ 3
|fbar{}@12\ 3
|fbar@12\ 3
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[]
function foo (); @12\ 3
|fbar{} @12\ 3
|fbar @12\ 3
|fbar\ @12\ 3
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

and the output:

> [image]

I'd use this with care. It's the kind of code that doesn't inspire confidence.

P.S.: If you want to make the code know more characters as “letter” you have to change the conditional:

```latex
  \ifnum %      vv If you want to \maketatletter :)
    % \ifnum0#1>63 \expandafter0\else\expandafter1\fi
      \ifnum0#1>64 \expandafter0\else\expandafter1\fi
      \ifnum0#1<91 \expandafter0\else\expandafter1\fi
        =0
```

for instance, changing the first `64` to `63` will make `@` act as a letter.

Comment: Great work! Perhaps this could even go into the official `listings` package as a new experimental feature?

Comment: @siracusa Thanks :) Modesty aside, I think it's a nice feature, although the code certainly has issues. I may try to contact Jobst if you don't find any obvious problems in this code while using it :)

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    keywords={function},
    escapeinside={|}{|}
}
\def\fbar{function bar ();}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[]
function foo ();
|\bgroup\endlinechar=-1 \scantokens\expandafter{\expandafter\egroup\expandafter|\fbar}
function baz ();
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    keywords={function},
    escapeinside={|}{|}
}
\begingroup
\catcode`\^^M=12 %
\csname@firstofone\endcsname{%
  \endgroup%
  \def\fbar{%
    function bar ();
    function baz ();%
  }%
}%
%

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[]
function foo ();
|\bgroup\endlinechar=-1 \scantokens\expandafter{\expandafter\egroup\expandafter|\fbar} Something in the same line as baz;
function bat ();
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]